# Dojo Tooltip Attach to Multiple Nodes: Element Selector Works, but not Class Selector

Tags: css-selectors, dojo, tooltip

I'm trying to use dojo Tooltips on a series of SVG elements that are tool buttons in my header. I'm using the method in the docs of attaching tooltips to multiple nodes like this:

```
new Tooltip({
    connectId: query('.header'),
    selector: 'svg',
    position: ['below'],
    getContent: function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('data-tooltiptext');
    }
});
```

And that works, but if I use a selector of '.tool' (every SVG has a class of tool on it) my getContent function never gets called. 'svg.tool' doesn't work as a selector either. The docs an several examples around the net *claim* class selectors will work, but I've only been able to get element selectors to work.

I'm requiring 'dojo/query' and I've tried using 'dojo/query!css3' but that doesn't seem to make a difference. I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm using dojo included with [ESRI's ArcGIS JS API library](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/), which reports a dojo version of 1.14.2.

Comment: could you post a representation sample html of your SVG buttons ...

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue when using the `selector` attribute while creating a `Menu`. Within an SVG element, element selectors (even comma-concatenated ones) work, but class selectors do not. Outside of the SVG element, they worked just fine. You can play around with this by using `dojo.query` in your browser's console to see which elements get selected.

I was able to solve the issue by changing the `selectorEngine` in my dojo config. Using any of `css3`, `css2.1`, and `css2` worked, so I think the issue may be in the `acme` engine. If you don't already have a dojo config, you can add it via a script tag:

```
<script>
 var dojoConfig = {
     selectorEngine: 'css3',
 };
</script>
```